# Docker mongodb connection refused on mac os when loading http://0.0.0.0:27017

Tags: python, mongodb, macos, docker, docker-for-mac

[Browser Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuX36.png) 
I have 2 docker containers running mongo:3.0.3 and python:2.7. And I have an app.py which connects to mongodb instance. In my app.py I have used port 5000 to map 27017. The app.py runs fine but when I visit http://0.0.0.0:5000  this connection refused error comes on terminal.

```
172.17.0.1 - - [01/Jul/2018 10:01:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/pythonApp/app.py", line 16, in form
    if posts.count()!=0:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1023, in count
    return self._count(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 985, in _count
    with self._socket_for_reads() as (sock_info, slave_ok):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 699, in _socket_for_reads
    with self._get_socket(read_preference) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 663, in _get_socket
    server = self._get_topology().select_server(selector)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 121, in select_server
address))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 97, in select_servers
    self._error_message(selector))
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I can't find any .conf files as this is a container. Any idea on how to get this fixed? :/

my docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/sizijay/dockerexercise/
see the long description for dockerfile

Comment: Just visit the ip Adress of the container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the Mongo container:

```
$ docker run -d -p "27017:27017" mongo
```

In your **app.py**, use **pymongo** *Connection*.

```
from pymongo import Connection
c = Connection(host=0.0.0.0, port=27017)
c.test_database
```

**Note:** the host is **0.0.0.0**.

Run your container:

```
$ docker run -d -p 5000:5000 sizijay/dockerexercise
```

If you use **localhost** as your host, **pymongo** will be looking inside the container from which is running (i.e. *sizijay/dockerexercise*).
When you use **0.0.0.0**, the connection will be to your *host machine*, which now has port 27017 bound to 27017 inside your mongo container.

---

A better alternative would be to use **docker-compose** to link your containers.

In this case, you need to create a file:
**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  myapp:
    image: sizijay/dockerexercise
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
```

In your **app.py**, use **pymongo** *Connection*.

```
from pymongo import Connection
c = Connection(host='db', port=27017)
c.test_database
```

**Note:** the host is **db**.

Now your host is not inside your **app** container, but inside the **db** service (i.e. the mongo container).

You can run docker-compose by:

```
$ docker build -t sizijay/dockerexercise .
$ cd location_of_docker-compose.yml
$ docker-compose up
```

Comment: mongo is already running

0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp
and when I visit 0.0.0.0:27017 in browser there's an echo "It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port."

so the problem is with app.py it can't connect

Comment: the 2 containers are already running 
mongo-> 0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp
sizijay/dockerexercise -> 0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp

Comment: @sizijay, Just because you exposed it on host doesn't mean it would work. When you use `localhost:27017` inside the `app.py` it is running inside the container in which only `5000` is the port which has something. So you test on host and say `27017` is accessible on localhost but that localhost is in context with your machine and not with respect to container

Comment: @TarunLalwani yeah. I understand now. the app.py is working fine when I run it without docker. so the problem is with linking the containers? right?

Comment: Yes, you need to use the container name or better launch the whole thing using a `docker-compose` config

Comment: @TarunLalwani linking the containers solved the problem. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution -- that does not use **docker-compose** -- is to run the two containers on the same bridge network (created using `docker network create <networkname>`) by using the `--network` flag in the `docker run` commands for both of the containers:

`docker run -p 27017:27017 --name mongo1 -d --network sizijaynetwork mongo`

`docker run -p 5000:5000 --name app1 -d --network sizijaynetwork appimage`

Then in your Python script you can do:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient(host = 'mongo1', port = 27017)
db = client.databaseName
```

Note that the host should be the name you assign to your Mongo container, and in case you don't use the `--name` flag, just use the default name for the container you can find under **NAMES** when you do `docker ps`

Comment: thank you. that's also working. good for less number of containers.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm using Mongoengine, the connection parameters are,

```
    db = connect(<database name>, host='mongo-server', port=27017)
```

And my docker-compose.yml is,

```
    version: "3.4"
    services:
    ...
    ...
        db:
           image: mongo:3.4
           container_name: mongo-server
           ports:
               - "27015:27017"
```

I am able to connect mongodb from my web application running as docker containers.